# While loop isn't working with two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to get the function to print incremented coordinates from input and it skips or doesn't execute the loop after input.

I've tried stripping the equation down to a barebones loop and it won't work.

I placed a while loop after to ensure that it's skipping/not executing my loop.

I've also tried changing "and" to "or".

```
interval = input("Please enter the interval increase for your coordinates: ")
Xstart = input("Start point for X: ")
Ystart = input("Start point for Y: ")
Xstop = input("Stop point for X: ")
Ystop = input("Stop point for Y: ")

while Xstart <= Xstop and Ystart <= Ystop:
    print(Xstart, Ystart)
    Xstart = Xstart + interval
    Ystart = Ystart + interval
```

Proof the loops work:

```
i = 1
while i < 6:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

I'm expecting it to print out the paired coordinates and then increment; it skips the loop altogether.

Comment: All the variables in the first piece of code are _strings_.

Comment: be careful, input() give you a str (text data), not a number, and while you can compare 2 strings together it's probably not what you want in this context.
to fix that put `int(...)` around the `input()` calls, it will convert the text to actual numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast each input `string` to an `int` so the exit condition `Xstart <= Xstop and Ystart <= Ystop` can be evaluated how you think it should.

```
interval = int(input("Please enter the interval increase for your coordinates: "))
Xstart = int(input("Start point for X: "))
Ystart = int(input("Start point for Y: "))
Xstop = int(input("Stop point for X: "))
Ystop = int(input("Stop point for Y: "))

while Xstart <= Xstop and Ystart <= Ystop:
    print(Xstart, Ystart)
    Xstart = Xstart + interval
    Ystart = Ystart + interval
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter the interval increase for your coordinates: 4
Start point for X: 5
Start point for Y: 6
Stop point for X: 10    
Stop point for Y: 10
5 6
9 10
```